# libgsl0ldbl, libgsl2 not installable on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

I am trying to install the [Vienna RNA package](https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/) for Ubuntu 17.10. I follow the following instructions:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:j-4/vienna-rna
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vienna-rna
```

and I get:

```
Package vienna-rna is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  viennarna:i386 viennarna
```

So I try:

```
sudo apt-get install viennarna
```

and I get:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 viennarna : Depends: libgsl0ldbl but it is not installable or
                      libgsl2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I install `libgsl0ldbl`, `libgsl2` because I wasn't able to do it using `apt-get install`?

Comment: Whan happens if you do `sudo apt install libgsl0ldbl`?

Comment: @fkraiem I get: `Package libgsl0ldbl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libgsl23 libgslcblas0:i386 libgsl23:i386 libgslcblas0`...however when I try to install `libgsl23` and `libgslcblas0` , it says they are already installed.